How to handle variable number of input/output files in Snakemake
I have a relatively simple pipeline with Snakemake.
However one of the tools in this pipeline is not really optimised, and has RAM overflow if the inputfile is too big.
I could split the files during analysis,and execute them in succession without a problem (confused where the overflow comes from in the first place), and combine the results into a file and continue.
I struggle to understand how I can do that in snakemake. I have tried with dynamic/expand, but I cannot get it to work
lets say my code looks like this:
rule all:
    input:
    "results/{motif}{file}.score"

run cmd1:
    input:
        "data/{file}.txt"
    output:
        "intermediate/{file}.fasta"
    shell:
        "bash cmd1.sh {input} > {output}

run cmd2: 
    input:
       "intermediate/{file}.fasta"
    output:
        "intermediate/{file}--{motif}.fasta"
    shell:
        "cmd2 input > output"
run cmd3:
    input:
        motif =  "data/{motif}.mf"
        seq = "intermediate/{file}--{motif}.fasta"
    output:
        "results/{file}--{motif}.score"
    run:
        some_function(motif,seq,output[0]

cmd2 is the problematic one.
How would I write the rules to split the data (in 1000 line chunks) execute the cmd2 for each of the chunks and combine them.
Could this reasonably be done with snakemake?
Or should I just write a function in python that does the split, running cmd2, combining and removing temp files? (kind of a pipeline in a pipeline)

I think what you are looking for is the checkpoint-option. This reevaluates the code after the rule is run (In this case to check how many files where created).
I dropped the motif parameter, because I am not sure how it is determined. Is this also not known beforehand, or do you have a set number of motifs to check for each file. If it is the first, checkpoints should help here as well, if its the second it should just be an additional parameter in the inputs and outputs.
rule all:
    input:
        expand("results/{file}.score", file = ["A","B","C"])


def get_file_names(wildcards):
    ck_output = checkpoints.cmd1.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    SMP, = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(ck_output, "{sample}.split"))
    return expand(os.path.join(ck_output, "{SAMPLE}.split"), SAMPLE=SMP)

checkpoint cmd1: #simulates Splitting of Input with seemingly randome output number
    input:
        "input/{file}.txt"
    output:
        directory("intermediate/{file}")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {output};
        N=$(((RANDOM%5)+1));
        for D in $(seq $N); do
            echo $RANDOM > {output}/$RANDOM.split
        done
        """

rule cmd2: #merges cmd1 results
    input:
        get_file_names
    output:
         "intermediate/{file}.fasta"
    shell:
        """
        cat {input} > {output}
        """

rule cmd3: #calculates the score of the fasta files
    input:
        "intermediate/{file}.fasta"
    output:
         "results/{file}.score"
    shell:
        """
        md5sum {input} > {output}
        """

To be honest, I rarely need to use checkpoints, so I am heavily based the code on  this blog post.

Checkpoints could be useful here as suggested by @kEks but I think here your own suggestion of "should I just write a function in python that does the split, running cmd2, combining and removing temp files?" will work. You can refine this a little by splitting this into two Snakemake rules - one which splits the input files and another which runs cmd2 and combines the output. Use a temporary(directory()) output to hold the split input files and to get Snakemake to clean up those temporary files for you.
A weakness of this approach is that you can't run your cmd2 on the chunks in parallel (or you have the resort to something xargs -P to do so). In that case a checkpoint could help, and my advice is that you should not try to incorporate a checkpoint until you have the workflow running happily in two separate parts.
The fundamental issue here is that, if you want each 1000-line chunk of input data to be processed as a separate job, you need to know how many lines are in the full file in order to know how many chunks/jobs there will be. Since Snakemake normally builds the entire DAG before it does any data processing this implies you have to generate and count the lines in the input files first, then build a new DAG with the correct number of sub-jobs. So you are best doing this in two separate Snakefiles and getting that working before combining everything with checkpoints.
In your particular case (I can't say without seeing more details) it may be that you know the size of the input files before the workflow is run. If so, no checkpoint is needed, because you can build the full DAG right away. Something like:
input_size = 6987 # for example
number_of_chunks = ( ( input_size - 1 ) // 1000 ) + 1

rule merge_results:
   output: "combined.out"
   input:  expand("chunk_{n}.in", n=range(number_of_chunks))

rule process_chunk:
   output: "chunk_{n}.out"
   input:  "chunk_{n}.in"
   shell:
        "cmd {input} > {output}

rule split_input:
   output: "chunk_{n}.in"
   shell:
      ...code here to put the right lines in the right chunk...

